# npm server js скачивается а не открывается в браузере, по идее должна только открываться

Tags: javascript, node.js

Каждый раз как я пытаюсь открыть страницу в браузере, она скачивается, а не открывается.

В терминале вписывал `npm run dev` для автоматической корректировки ст.

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

if (req.method === 'GET') {
     res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'txt/html'
    })
})

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running...')
})
```

Comment: Кто бы ещё знал что вы открываете. Навскидку `text/html`, а не `txt`

Comment: Спасибо! Не заметил)